# GDB Exits/Crashes while Trying to Debug TensorFlow C++ Code

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb, tensorflow

Whenever I try to debug `TensorFlow's C++` code with `Eclipse` + `GDB`, I get `GDB` crashing, or actually exiting with: `error code = -1`.

As long as I don't set a breakpoint in `TensorFlow's C++` code, the program runs just fine. But when I do, and when the debugger gets to the breakpoint, it crashes after a few seconds with `error code -1`. There is nothing meaningful in the GDB traces which can explain this behavior.

The `GDB` version I am using is `7.7.1`, running with `Eclipse Neon` under `Ubuntu 14.04`.

TensorFlow is compiled in debug mode. I don't think that Eclipse is missing the debug symbols for it, as it is not complaining that those are missing (and also, occasionally, the debugger is able to step through a few steps in the code before it crashes).

An easy way to reproduce is to try and debug the label_image example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html

Compile it and then create a 'C/C++ Application' debug configuration in Eclipse, directing it to the compiled binary of the label_image app.

Comment: What happens when you run gdb from the command-line?

Comment: Just tried it. Seems much more stable. Maybe the issue is related to Eclipse? I have tried two versions, including the latest Neon one.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem with **GDB** on macOS. But, I finally succeeded to debug `tf` with `lldb`. And I also found that using **[VisualStudio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)** + **[lldb](https://lldb.llvm.org/)** makes it easy for debugging.

Here is **[my way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689863/how-to-debug-tensorflow-internal-c-code-efficiently-with-ideintelj-or-xcode)** of debugging. Maybe you can give it a try.