# how to debug tensorflow internal c++ code efficiently with IDE(intelJ or Xcode) on mac?

Tags: c++, debugging, tensorflow

I want to debug the c++ source code of tensorflow, e.g tensorflow/c/c_api.cc . I've found some answers about how to debug the c++ code with gdb,but I want to know if it's possible to debug it with ide like Xcode, which can be very comfortable for editing and debug.Thanks .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much search and dig, I finally succeed to debug the tensorflow  c++ source code in an acceptable way.I used bazel+vscode+lldb on mac.

**bazel**: build the target(Also can be done by vscode).
**visual studio code**: debug and read code
**lldb** : debug backend

my vscode lanch.json is :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bazel-out/darwin_x86_64-dbg/bin/tensorflow/cc/example/example",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: vscode debug tf]